# Version of MSI to use for SharePoint online management from PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, sharepoint, powershell-3.0

The following KB article is a rather vague on which MSI to use in what circumstances:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588

There are obviously 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Would you use the 64-bit version on 64-bit Windows 10 given that when you launch PowerShell, you get the 64-bit flavour unless you specifically load the 32-bit version?

But what's with the 4727-1200 and 4915-1200 versions?

[image: Different PS modules for SharePoint]

UPDATE: I tried installing all four of them in a VM reverting back to pre-install each time and none of them appear to work. I get this error when launching SharePoint Online Management Shell:

[image: PowerShell error]

Comment: Okay, so the error was caused by not running PowerShell as administrator. So 64-bit version worked on 64-bit Windows 10. But still need to know what the differences is between the 4727 and 4915 versions of the MSI

Comment: 4727  was the previous build of the Sharepoint Mangement scripts.  The file you would have wanted is either of the `*_4915_1200` files.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author resolved this by installing the current version of the Sharepoint Online Powershell scripts.  Additionally, their original problem was caused by not running the PowerShell shell as an Administrator.  More importantly, the author's problem, can now no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time passes and Microsoft have released a new version of the SharePoint Online Management shell and in this download there are only two versions for 32-bit PowerShell and 64-bit PowerShell. So my question is kind of moot now so answering.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same Issue, and resolved it by setting the Execution policy for my machine. [Refer my Original Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243899/error-occurred-while-loading-the-module-of-microsoft-online-sharepoint-powershel)

```
  set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy unrestricted
```

Or

```
set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy remotesigned
```